# Stacked column bar chart over two variables

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have some data as shown below

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = {
'gender':['female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male'],
'age':['15 - 19', '20 - 24', '25 - 29', '30 - 34', '35 - 39', '> 39', '15 - 19', '20 - 24', '25 - 29', '30 - 34', '35 - 39', '> 39', '15 - 19', '20 - 24', '25 - 29', '30 - 34', '35 - 39', '> 39', '35 - 39', '> 39', '15 - 19', '20 - 24', '25 - 29', '30 - 34', '35 - 39', '> 39', '15 - 19', '20 - 24', '25 - 29', '30 - 34', '35 - 39', '> 39', '15 - 19', '20 - 24', '25 - 29', '30 - 34', '35 - 39', '> 39', '25 - 29', '30 - 34'],  
'baseline':['M1', 'M1', 'M1', 'M1', 'M1', 'M4', 'M4', 'M2', 'M2', 'M2', 'M2', 'M2', 'M3', 'M3', 'M3', 'M3', 'M5', 'M5', 'M5', 'M5', 'M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4', 'M5', 'M2', 'M2', 'M2', 'M3', 'M3', 'M3', 'M3', 'M4', 'M4', 'M4', 'M5', 'M5', 'M5', 'M5', 'M5'],
'endline':['M5', 'M3', 'M1', 'M1', 'M1', 'M4', 'M4', 'M5', 'M2', 'M5', 'M5', 'M3', 'M3', 'M3', 'M4', 'M4', 'M4', 'M1', 'M1', 'M2', 'M5', 'M5', 'M5', 'M1', 'M1', 'M1', 'M1', 'M4', 'M4', 'M4', 'M4', 'M4', 'M3', 'M3', 'M3', 'M3', 'M2', 'M2', 'M2', 'M2']}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head()

cross_tab_prop = pd.crosstab(index = df['gender'],
                             columns = df['baseline'],
                             normalize = "index")

cross_tab_prop.plot(kind = 'bar', 
                    stacked = True, 
                    colormap = 'tab10', 
                    figsize = (10, 6))

plt.legend(loc = "upper left", ncol = 5)
plt.xlabel("Gender")
plt.ylabel("Proportion")
```

and would like to produce a chart as shown below

[image]

I would appreciate any hints on how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With seaborn, the approach would be:

- convert the dataframe to [long form](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data)
- create a `sns.displot()` with `multiple='fill'` and `col='gender'`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

data = {
'gender':['female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male'],
'baseline':['M1', 'M1', 'M1', 'M1', 'M1', 'M4', 'M4', 'M2', 'M2', 'M2', 'M2', 'M2', 'M3', 'M3', 'M3', 'M3', 'M5', 'M5', 'M5', 'M5', 'M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4', 'M5', 'M2', 'M2', 'M2', 'M3', 'M3', 'M3', 'M3', 'M4', 'M4', 'M4', 'M5', 'M5', 'M5', 'M5', 'M5'],
'endline':['M5', 'M3', 'M1', 'M1', 'M1', 'M4', 'M4', 'M5', 'M2', 'M5', 'M5', 'M3', 'M3', 'M3', 'M4', 'M4', 'M4', 'M1', 'M1', 'M2', 'M5', 'M5', 'M5', 'M1', 'M1', 'M1', 'M1', 'M4', 'M4', 'M4', 'M4', 'M4', 'M3', 'M3', 'M3', 'M3', 'M2', 'M2', 'M2', 'M2']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_long = df.melt(id_vars='gender', value_vars=['baseline', 'endline'],
                  var_name='which', value_name='property')
g = sns.displot(data=df_long, x='which', hue='property', col='gender', multiple='fill')
g.set(xlabel='', ylabel='')
g.axes[0, 0].yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.displot multiple='fill']

Here is the same plot with different styling:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter, MultipleLocator
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

# df_long = ...
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
g = sns.displot(data=df_long, x='which', hue='property', col='gender', multiple='fill', shrink=0.7, palette='turbo')
g.set(xlabel='', ylabel='')
g.axes[0, 0].yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(.1))
g.axes[0, 0].yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))
g.axes[0, 0].set_xlim(-.6, 1.6)
sns.despine(left=True)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)
```

[image: sns.displot looking like one subplot]

Comment: Thanks so much @JohanC for the proposed solution. I sincerely appreciate

Comment: am trying to include title and subtitle with no success. Any hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here seaborn creates a `FacetGrid` , a grid of subplots. Each subplot already has a title. You can use  `g.fig.suptitle('Overall Title')` to set a title to everything.  If you also want a subtitle, you could try `g.fig.suptitle('Overall Title\nSubtitle')`.  As there probably won't be enough space at the top, you can use something like `g.fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.8)` to reserve more space.

Comment: thanks a ton! I appreciate your valuable insights.

Comment: sorry for coming back with another question. Is it possible to have the subplots in more than one row? I have just modified the original code to include age and the plot seems too cluttered. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a parameter `col_wrap=...` telling after how many columns a new row should be started. Other parameters are `height=` (the height in inches of an individual subplot) and `aspect=` (the aspect ratio of `width/height` of the subplots).

Comment: Thanks @JohanC I tried it out in ```sns.displot()``` and got the error "IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed" in ```g.axes[0, 0].yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(.1))```